# Update background image in swift using image picker

Tags: ios, swift, uiimagepickercontroller

I am trying to simply allow the user to select an image from their library, and have that replace the default background. It all seems to work up until the image should be replaced, and I get stuck with the same default image.

For clarity: The image picker is being presented, allowing the user to select an image, it then gets dismissed, but does not replace the background image.

```
import UIKit

class CharmanderViewController: UIViewController {


@IBOutlet weak var background: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var charmander: UIImageView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    background.addSubview(charmander)
    let panGesture = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(pan(_ :)))
    charmander.addGestureRecognizer(panGesture)

    let scaleGesture = UIPinchGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(scale(_ :)))
    charmander.addGestureRecognizer(scaleGesture)
}

@objc func scale (_ sender:UIPinchGestureRecognizer){
    if let view = sender.view {
        view.transform = view.transform.scaledBy(x: sender.scale, y: sender.scale)
    }
    sender.scale = 1.0
}
@objc func pan (_ sender:UIPanGestureRecognizer){
    let translation = sender.translation(in: self.view)
    if let view = sender.view {
        view.center = CGPoint(x: view.center.x + translation.x,
                              y: view.center.y + translation.y)
    }
    sender.setTranslation(CGPoint.zero, in: self.view)

    if sender.state == .began {
        print ("drag started")
    } else if sender.state == .changed {
        print ("dragging")
    } else if sender.state == .ended {
        print ("drag ended")
    }


}

@IBAction func getImage(_ sender: Any) {
    if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(.photoLibrary) {
        let imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
        imagePicker.delegate = self as? UIImagePickerControllerDelegate & UINavigationControllerDelegate 
        imagePicker.sourceType = .photoLibrary
        imagePicker.mediaTypes = UIImagePickerController.availableMediaTypes(for: .photoLibrary)!
        self.present(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}

func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
    background.image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}


@IBAction func Share(_ sender: Any) {
    let renderer = UIGraphicsImageRenderer (size: background.bounds.size)
    let image = renderer.image { context in
        background.drawHierarchy(in: background.bounds, afterScreenUpdates: true)
    }

    let shareViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [image], applicationActivities: [])
    present (shareViewController, animated: true)
}
}
```

I've tried using

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    updateYourUI()
}
```

but I can't quite figure out how to correctly write a function that replaces the image. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Does the image picker appear? Is the `didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo` delegate called when the user chooses an image?

Comment: Yes the image picker is appearing and allowing me to select an image. And I am not entirely sure about the second question.

Comment: Add a breakpoint and use the debugger. Or add a `print` statement to `didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo` and see it is called.

Comment: And why do you make the `charmander` image view a subview of the `background` image view? Perhaps you don't see a change because the `background` image view` is hidden before the other.

Comment: It does not appear to be getting called. https://gyazo.com/d6662544ed5020e1435b1a4412e10b1e
That test did not print "yes"

Comment: Are you seeing charmander instead of the background? If so, it is likely because you add charmander as a subview of the background, so charmander image overlaps the background. In didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo change background to charmander and see if it changes.

Comment: I'm sorry for all the confusion, i'm still learning. 

I have now removed Charmander as a subview of the background as that does seem to be unnecessary. To make it clear Charmander is tiny, so he would not cover up a background.

What it looks like: https://gyazo.com/b1076ddc9379fa47ea61739a90e67cea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding your UIImagePickerControllerDelegate and  UINavigationControllerDelegate at the top of the file:

```
class CharmanderViewController: UIViewController, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {
```

and in your getImage() func, set the imagePickerController delegate to just self:

```
@IBAction func getImage(_ sender: Any) {
    if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(.photoLibrary) {
        let imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
        imagePicker.delegate = self
        imagePicker.sourceType = .photoLibrary
        imagePicker.mediaTypes = 
        UIImagePickerController.availableMediaTypes(for: .photoLibrary)!
        self.present(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

And in your didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo method, make a check to see if you can cast the info as UIImage:

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
    guard let originalImage = info["UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"] as? UIImage else {return}
    background.image = originalImage
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this, it works. Through the initial questions in the comments, and going over your answer I do believe I understand where I went wrong, so even more appreciated. Thanks again!